# Cross-subdomain / port socket.io - how to deal with that?

Tags: browser, node.js, cross-domain, socket.io

I'm facing cross-subdomain / port problem with Socket.io. In example in Opera, when I disable Flash Socket.io automatically fallback to JSONP - and that's not good (XHR is way better).

I'm using now test subdomain, let's call it test.example.com. I tried many solutions.

- `http://data.test.example.com:80`
- `http://test.example.com:8000`
- `http://example.com:8000`

None of solutions worked. Any hints? Maybe should I use nginx as reverse proxy? Something like `http://test.example.com/data/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm facing cross-subdomain / port problem with Socket.io. In example
>   in Opera, when I disable Flash Socket.io automatically fallback to
>   JSONP - and that's not good (XHR is way better).

Good question. I also have a "[spinning throbber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680015/stop-browser-throbber-spinning-for-comet-using-iframe)" when using Opera. But after some searching I think that Opera does not yet [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing#Browser_support) [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). You have to use CORS to get around [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). I think the only option for socket.io would be to add server-sent-event(socket.io does not yet have server-sent-event, which I think has [cross domain support](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#web-messaging)). You could also try and [fill an issue with socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/issues)(don't think they will put this in front of issues queue). But maybe [this issue might](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/pull/230#commits-pushed-2fc3b56) be working server-sent-event

Also I think you could just enable flash-sockets instead, which fixes all problems. Almost [all(99%) user do have flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/).

Or you like you are saying you could use [Nginx as reverse proxy](http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets). Also a some users do use [HAProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360221/haproxy-websocket-disconnection/4737648#4737648) instead.

Comment: Flash fall backs are no good :( implement server-side events instead.

Comment: plugins are slow, laggy, easy to crash, leaky abstractions and HTML/DOM are always superior.

Comment: True that, Flash gets you started really fast though! Works in almost all browsers(99%) and has very good support in socket.io. No spinning throbber for example...