# Simple ajax call seems to be blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Really simple question. I trying to test a Restful webservice that I am developing, and have this simple ajax call (using jquery):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
   $(document).ready(function() { 
     var url = '/index.php/gettest/reallyLongRequest';    
     $.ajax({
       url: url,
       dataType:'text',
       success:function(data) { $('#result').html(data);},
       error:function(xhr,err,e) { alert ("Error: " + err);}
     });                
  });
 </script>
```

This runs when the page loads. As it's running, the page is blocking; i.e., (I can see the hourglass next to the mouse pointer) no other user actions can be handled. (Btw, this particular get request--intentionally--takes a very long time to return).

Why is this? A(asynchronous)JAX right? Obviously I am making a beginners mistake. Any ideas, please?

When I attempt this using plain javascript (no library) it works as expected. Does this have something to do with Jquery's handling of the xhr onreadystatechange?

Thank you for looking.

EDIT: multiple people have suggested setting async: true, which as it happens, is the default in jquery, and as such has no effect.

EDIT: As previously mentioned, if I use plain javascript and start this with a timer, e.g., `window.setInterval(function() { startLongPoll(); }, 5000)`
It updates as expected, without appearing to block. Ideas, anyone?

Comment: I have no clue if this is related, but have you tried on a different browser?

Comment: Looks like my previous statement was untrue; upon further inspection it only happens in google chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what I did to solve the problem:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
   $.getJSON("veryLongRequest", function(json) {
   alert("JSON Result: " + json[0].id);});
  }, 500); // You may need to adjust this to a longer delay.
});
```

Note: I am using the short-hand jquery method, "getJSON" which is a wrapper for the ajax call with datatype set to "json". However, this solution will work for all ajax requests.

Referenced:

[Stop the browser "throbber of doom" while loading comet/server push iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064782/stop-the-browser-throbber-of-doom-while-loading-comet-server-push-iframe/1066729#1066729)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should default to true, but try adding `async: true` to your ajax json parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Does the code below work as expected?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
   //$(document).ready(function() { 
     var url = '/index.php/gettest/reallyLongRequest';    
     $.ajax({
       url: url,
       dataType:'text',
       success:function(data) { $('#result').html(data);},
       error:function(xhr,err,e) { alert ("Error: " + err);}
     });                
  //});
 </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. Same issue. Thanks for the suggestion though. Also, please see my latest EDIT

Answer (score -4):

May want to try and Add  `async:true`

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
       $(document).ready(function() { 
         var url = '/index.php/gettest/reallyLongRequest';    
         $.ajax({
           url: url,
           async:true,
           dataType:'text',
           success:function(data) { $('#result').html(data);},
           error:function(xhr,err,e) { alert ("Error: " + err);}
         });                
      });
     </script>
```

Comment: async is true by default. Why would that help?

Comment: @Chris Kooken as JB Nizet said, async is true by default. To be sure, I did try that, and still have the same issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't know why this has two up votes, since (as other's have said as well) async is true by default, and my posted code clearly shows that async is not set to false. Please see my own posted answer for solution to this issue. Thanks for looking.