# Long Ajax Request in Chrome Shows Waiting

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, asynchronous, ajax-polling

In FF and IE, I make an Ajax request (Jquery Post) to my server. The requests calls a sql stored procedure which queries for 30 seconds before it returns data (or immediately if data is available). Data is then returned to my javascript and I preform actions based off it.

All is fine, until I get to Chrome, which will get the updates, but shows the loading pointer and loading page icon in the browser.

This call is made each time the request is returned, so it seems - to the user -as if chrome is always waiting for the page to load.

Is there any way around this?

Regards.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe your `async` property is set to `false`?

Comment: The post goes to an async enabled aspx page which then calls an asyc stored procedure.

Comment: No, I mean the jQuery AJAX call itself? Is it `async : true`? Whether or not your ASPX and/or SQL SP is async won't matter if your AJAX call isn't, 'cause your browser will irrevocably be "waiting" anyway.

Comment: Jquery Post is by default async.

Comment: Yeap, I know that as well. Just making sure that it didn't turn out that `async` was turned off by accident or something. Hence, the comment, instead of a usual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced the same issue. Fortunately, I found another SO question that was very useful. Here is an example of what I did to solve the problem:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
   $.getJSON("veryLongRequest", function(json) {
   alert("JSON Result: " + json[0].id);});
  }, 500); // You may need to adjust this to a longer delay.
});
```

Note: I am using the short-hand jquery method, "getJSON" which is a wrapper for the ajax call with datatype set to "json". However, this solution will work for all ajax requests.

Referenced:

[Stop the browser "throbber of doom" while loading comet/server push iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064782/stop-the-browser-throbber-of-doom-while-loading-comet-server-push-iframe/1066729#1066729)