# Prevent mobile Safari from showing loading indicator while _changes listener is active

Tags: couchdb, long-polling, couchapp, kanso

### The Setup

After a page finishes loading, I'm adding a `_changes` listener to a couchdb `longpoll` feed (just in case it matters, I'm using [this](https://github.com/kanso/db/blob/master/db.js#L831) function in the [Kanso](http://kan.so) `db` module).

Once the listener is added, mobile Safari's loading indicator starts spinning and it doesn't stop until the listener is removed.

### The Problem

This makes users think the app is constantly downloading something.

### The Question

Is there any way to make mobile Safari's loading indicator spin only when a change notification is received?

If not, is there a way to completely prevent mobile Safari's loading indicator from spinning?

Comment: This is a difficult one to Google for. One possible clue: are you running this code from the `document.ready` event? This answer indicates that if you postpone your execution, you will avoid the "throbber of doom": http://stackoverflow.com/a/7198241/2938

Comment: See also http://blog.kwwika.com/?tag=throbberofdoom -- I'm not confident enough to make this an official answer. If it works for you, would you please set an answer and mark it accepted? If it doesn't... we'll keep trying I guess.

Comment: @JasonSmith I have seen both of the posts you linked. I'm adding the changes listener long after the page has finished loading. Delaying the addition of the `_changes` listener gives the desired behavior in desktop Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. However, no matter when I add the `_changes` listener, mobile Safari starts spinning the moment the listener is added. It's rumored that an [event source](https://github.com/indutny/couchdb/commit/a152fb950bff92bc279a81570d96cb77cd71e48b) `_changes` feed won't trigger the spinner, but I proceed cautiously with an untested patch. Thoughts?

Comment: I saw the event source thing too. If you can get a failing test case and take that to the CouchDB list, we could merge that patch for the next release.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can come up with.