# Stop browser's spinning wheel

Tags: scala, playframework, comet

i am using comet in my playframework application. it is to receive server side events in the browser. i am using it by setting an iframe src to a method of my controller. it is working perfectly fine. But there is one issue. from the start of page load spinning wheel of browser start spinning and it never stops which gives viewer an impression that page is still loading. is there any posibillity that i could stop it?

Comment: Does your wheel start spinning on open HTTP requests? Maybe you have some js service, which helds all requests to server? If so, you should be able to distinguish comet requests from common requests

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064782/stop-the-browser-throbber-of-doom-while-loading-comet-server-push-iframe